# When did zfs-fuse become such a fundamental dependency on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, zfs

I installed Fedora 26 recently.  Some recent dnf updates I made pulled in zfs-fuse upon which lots of packages are now dependent (qemu*, gluster*, libvirt*, gnome-boxes, ...).

I am looking for the history of this dependency and the rationale behind it.

It makes it difficult to install kernel-based zfs (zfs-on-linux) since zfs-fuse and zfs (ZoL) are conflicting packages.  Attempting to remove zfs-fuse will want to remove all the dependent packages as well.

Secondary question - is there any recent comparison of performance of kernel-based zfs and zfs-fuse?  This is related to my primary question - if zfs-fuse is substantially equivalent to kernel zfs performance-wise, then perhaps it's not as problematic to have lots of packages depend on zfs-fuse.  But if there's a significant difference between ZoL and zfs-fuse, I'd like to be able to either have the packages be able to co-exist or at least be interchangeable.

Comment: You could always just force-remove libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs so you can remove it.

Comment: Yes, I could - I may or may not decide to do that.  The questions posed still stand, however.

Comment: [Here's the bug report from the changelog. Ask away.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1471912)

Comment: That bug report (and referenced libvirt mailing list post) is a good reference to the history and rationale (and mechanism of the dependency).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Fedora 27 (beta now, release next week!), at least, I see this in the spec file:

```
%if %{with_storage_zfs}
# Support any conforming implementation of zfs. On stock Fedora
# this is zfs-fuse, but could be zfsonlinux upstream RPMs
BuildRequires: /sbin/zfs
BuildRequires: /sbin/zpool
%endif
```

which means this is using *file* dependencies, specifically so that alternate implementations can be used. You should be able to use `dnf swap zfs-fuse zfs` to replace the Fedora RPM with your alternate one.

I think *probably* we should move to using soft dependencies (`Recommends` instead of `Requires`) for a lot of these, but apparently libvirt doesn't deal super-gracefully with missing drivers at runtime.